# Why do I have to detect displays for my 2nd display each time I resume from suspend?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, suspend

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Saucy HWE and Nvidia 331.20 with GeForce 310.  I have two identical 1440x900 displays.  Nearly each time I resume from suspend, I have to detect displays to get my 2nd display to come back.  Sometimes I have to press the button several times and sometimes I get unknown display for the second display and the resolution is at 640x480 until I press detect displays a few more times.

The primary display is connected with dual link DVI, and the second display is connect with single link DVI adapter to display port on the graphics card.

Is this normal, or does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue in Ubuntu 14.04 using Nvidia 331.38 and was able to fix it by running `sudo nvidia-settings` while both screens were working, selecting the "X Server Display Configuration" tab, clicking the "Save to X Configuration File" button, and saving to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Now I can suspend and resume with both screens coming back!

Comment: What about if I do have two different workplaces (work, home) with different displays. I have note that pressing "Displays"->"detects displays do the trick". Maybe a keyboard shortcut for detect displays is better.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an older nvidia card.  For me this was fixed by configuring my screens in nvidia-settings-manager instead of ARandR.

Comment: You put me on the right path! I found more of the info I needed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/456470/cant-save-nvidia-settings-for-screens-after-reboot