# Confused about XORG setup

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I've got a dual monitor setup running nicely, but one of the dual monitors has to be 'turned on' every time I login.

To be clear: I boot the machine and both screens are displaying perfectly. But once I login, boom, the left one turns off. Manually running Nvidia Config allows me to turn the missing monitor on, but I've no idea where to save the settings.

Obviously, there is a user specific config somewhere that is turning off the second monitor.

Any helps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't save nvidia settings for screens after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456470/cant-save-nvidia-settings-for-screens-after-reboot)

Comment: No not really. For some reason no matter how I launch nvidia-settings it never saves a file properly due to perms.

Comment: `sudo nvidia-settings`

Comment: Nope that doesn't do it. What I need to know is what secondary settings are undoing the correct setup:  
- when I show the login page, both screens are on  
- when I login, after a few moments (user settings loading?) the one screen turns off <-- I need to fix this.