Ubuntu 24.04 and Nvidia driver: Cannot write back the nvidia settings
I have an ubuntu 24.04 LTS new installation.
Hardware: CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 7600 6-Core, Graphics card: GeForce RTX 3050.
Desktops: MATE, Ubuntu (for test purpose).
Due to problems with the Nouveau driver I switched to the nvidia driver 550.
Then I called nvidia-settings (automatically installed
together with the nvidia driver) and altered settings there.
When I click "Save to X Configuration File", the application wants to save to
/etc/X11/xorg.conf by default.
When I click "Save" then, I have to authenticate as sudoer.
But thereafter the following message appears:
"Unable to open X config file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' for writing".
Even when I touch the file before trying to write it and set the file mode to -rw-rw-rw-, the same message appears.
The effect is: Each time after login I have to newly apply the changes in nvidia-settings.
Any ideas?

This question is similar to: Which nvidia driver from additional drivers option should I choose? and  Unable to switch back to the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver after switching to the open source driver. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The error message from nvidia-settings is misleading.
Actually the solution is quite simple:
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/screen-resolution-extra/nvidia-polkit
posted 12-25-2021, 02:36 by Member Paul
posted 11-23-2021 by aaerrolla in the nvidia developer forums
Actually,
the nvidia-settings may also be written to a file in
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d. The names of files there should start with two digits
followed by a minus sign; the remainder is arbitrary. The files are then
processed in the order of the starting number. If other files are already
there, the nvidia-settings should take the last place.
Incidentally,
when nvidia-settings is quit, it additionally writes a file named
.nvidia-settings-rc to the user's home directory.
That file lists some "ConfigProperties" and "Attributes". But CAUTION,
this is NOT the content which has to be saved to the X configuration file.

I tried so many things and nothing worked for me until I followed the steps in this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/926564/1653420

This worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04:

sudo nvidia-settings and change whatever settings you want,

save nvidia xorg configuration in /etc/X11/xorg.conf
go to

ubuntu Settings -> Displays and click the Apply button (if the button is disabled, try to do some dummy modifications).


Number 3 may sound really silly, but that was what saved me.

With the only caveat that I had to change the Refresh Rate in Ubuntu Settings to 60Hz before I was able to hit the Apply button.
I hope this helps someone.
